# Split JSON python string to pass to function

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How could I try and split my JSON with all the movies and send them separately to the finalScore function and then append to my list at the end?

Sorry the explain and code was big, I was really unsure of describing and showing my problem without showing what I have done it.

This is my current code:

```
import datetime, json

def jsonData(data):
    return json.loads(data)

def findContentInformation(content):
    contentData = convert_content_data(content)

    for info in contentData:
        contentBaseScore = info['popularityScore']
        contentBrand = info['brand']
        contentType = info['contentType']
        contentName = info['title']
        contentInformation = [contentBaseScore, contentBrand, contentType, contentName]
        
   
    return contentInformation

#Calculator the overall rating for the film
def getRating(content_data, userBrandRate, userTypeRate):
    
    contentScore = {}

    #RATING
    rating = 0

    # Collecting information from the content to be tested
    contentInfo = findContentInformation(content_data) # The content being tested
    popularityScore += contentInfo[0] #Find base score and add this to popScore

    #getBrandRating = str((userBrandPreference[contentInfo[1]])) # Get brand preference

    # Check if brand preference rating is a valid rating type
    if brandRating in Ratings:
        popularityScore += Ratings[brandRating] # Get the ratings score & update popScore
    else:
        print("Unrecognized rating value found in this search")

    user_content_type_preference = convert_type_preferences(content_type_preferences)
    typeRating = getTypeRating(user_content_type_preference, contentInfo) # Get the type rating

    # Check if type rating is a valid rating
    if typeRating in Ratings:
        popularityScore += Ratings[typeRating] # Update the popScore based on the rating score 
    else:
        print("Unrecognized rating value found in this search")

    contentScore[contentInfo[3]] = popularityScore
    popularityScore = 0

    return contentScore

result = getRating(content_data)
```

My output with only one movie (not sure how to use all the movies in the JSON)

JSON string:

```
content_data = """[{ "title": "Spider-Man", "brand": "Marvel",
"Rating": 98, "contentIs": "movie" }]"""
```

Output:

```
[{'Spider-Man': 128}]
```

Comment: Can you try shortening the code to a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it feels like you're making things unnecessarily complex. For example, you have three functions (`convert_content_data`, `convert_preferences` and `convert_type_preferences`) that all do the same thing - they all take one JSON encoded string and parse it. Turning those three functions into one would still be one too many functions, because I don't think `json.loads`, as a single side-effect, is a good candidate for an entirely separate function in the first place.

You do quite a bit of conversion also - from a JSON encoded string to a dictionary. You do that multiple times. Why not convert all your JSON **once** at the start of the program? Doing so will let you work with dictionaries for the rest of your tasks. Once you have a list of dictionaries, you can think of each dictionary as being one "movie-object", since that is what each dictionary represents. The brand- and content type JSON strings can also be converted once at the start of the program (instead of multiple times throughout the entire program).

---

EDIT - I've updated my example code.

First, I think you should put your movie data in a separate JSON file, so that you're not poluting your source code with a huge string literal. Let's name it `movies.json`:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Spider-Man",
        "brand": "Marvel",
        "availability": ["CA","FR","US"],
        "availableDate": "2019-11-12T05:00:00.000Z",
        "isKidsContent": true,
        "popularityScore": 98,
        "contentType": "movie"
    },
    
    {
        "title": "Float",
        "brand": "Pixar",
        "availability": ["US"],
        "availableDate": "2019-11-12T05:00:00.000Z",
        "isKidsContent": true,
        "popularityScore": 87,
        "contentType": "short"
    },
    {
        "title": "Avatar",
        "brand": "21st Century Fox",
        "availability": ["US","CA","FR","ES","DE"],
        "availableDate": "2019-11-12T05:00:00.000Z",
        "isKidsContent": false,
        "popularityScore": 99,
        "contentType": "movie"
    },
    
    {
        "title": "Chapter 1: The Mandalorian",
        "brand": "Star Wars", "availability": ["US","CA"],
        "availableDate": "2019-11-02T23:00:00.000Z",
        "isKidsContent": false,
        "popularityScore":  92,
        "contentType": "series"
    },
    
    {
        "title": "Marvel Studios Avengers: Endgame",
        "brand": "Marvel",
        "availability": ["CA","FR","ES","DE","US"],
        "availableDate": "2019-11-11T23:00:00.000Z",
        "isKidsContent": false,
        "popularityScore": 87,
        "contentType": "movie"
    },
    
    {
        "title": "Disney Mickey Mouse Clubhouse: Mickey Goes Fishing",
        "brand": "Disney",
        "availability": ["US"],
        "availableDate": "2019-09-11T22:00:00.000Z",
        "isKidsContent": true,
        "popularityScore": 75,
        "contentType": "series"
    },
    
    {
        "title": "Disney High School Musical: The Musical: The Series: Act Two",
        "brand": "Disney",
        "availability": ["US","FR","ES"],
        "availableDate": "2020-01-10T08:00:00.000Z",
        "isKidsContent": false,
        "popularityScore": 97,
        "contentType": "series"
    }
]
```

Then, I would also create a JSON file for all of your users. This is where you would store the user preferences. Let's name it `users.json`:

```
[

    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "preferences": {
            "brand": {
                "Star Wars": "love",
                "Disney": "like",
                "Marvel": "dislike",
                "Pixar": "dislike"
            },
            "contentType": {
                "movie": "like",
                "series": "like",
                "short": "dislike"
            }
        }
    },
    
    {
        "name": "Joe",
        "preferences": {
            "brand": {
                "Star Wars": "dislike",
                "Disney": "dislike",
                "Marvel": "dislike",
                "Pixar": "dislike"
            },
            "contentType": {
                "movie": "like",
                "series": "like",
                "short": "dislike"
            }
        }
    }
    
]
```

This `users.json` file has two users named `Bob` and `Joe`, with different preferences.

Then, the code:

```
def evaluate_score(user, movie):
    """
    Evaluates and returns the score a user would assign to
    a given movie based on the user's brand- and content-type preferences.
    """

    ratings = {
        "dislike": -20,
        "indifferent": 0,
        "like": 10,
        "adore": 30,
        "love": 50
    }

    brand_score = ratings.get(user["preferences"]["brand"].get(movie["brand"])) or 0
    content_type_score = ratings.get(user["preferences"]["contentType"].get(movie["contentType"])) or 0

    return movie["popularityScore"] + brand_score + content_type_score


def get_all_scores(user, movies):

    for movie in movies:
        yield {
            "title": movie["title"],
            "score": evaluate_score(user, movie)
        }
    

def main():

    import json
    from operator import itemgetter

    with open("movies.json", "r") as file:
        movies = json.load(file)

    with open("users.json", "r") as file:
        users = json.load(file)

    for user in users:
        print(user["name"].center(16, "-"))
        for movie in sorted(get_all_scores(user, movies), key=itemgetter("score"), reverse=True):
            print("{}: {}".format(movie["title"], movie["score"]))
        print()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
------Bob-------
Chapter 1: The Mandalorian: 152
Disney High School Musical: The Musical: The Series: Act Two: 117
Avatar: 109
Disney Mickey Mouse Clubhouse: Mickey Goes Fishing: 95
Spider-Man: 88
Marvel Studios Avengers: Endgame: 77
Float: 47

------Joe-------
Avatar: 109
Spider-Man: 88
Disney High School Musical: The Musical: The Series: Act Two: 87
Chapter 1: The Mandalorian: 82
Marvel Studios Avengers: Endgame: 77
Disney Mickey Mouse Clubhouse: Mickey Goes Fishing: 65
Float: 47

>>>
```

We've got two functions and one generator:

`evaluate_score` (which I called `get_movie_score` before) takes a user dictionary and a movie dictionary, and returns the score (an integer) which this user would assign to the given movie, based on that user's preferences.
`get_all_scores` is a generator that takes a user and a list of movie dictionaries. It gets the scores for all movies, according to that user, and yields dictionaries - where each dictionary contains two key-value pairs: The movie title, and the final score assigned by that user. This generator will be userful later in the `main` function, when we want to print the final result in descending order.
`main` is the main entry-point of the entire script. It first opens and parses our two JSON files, and then, for every user, print a sorted summary (in descending order based on score) of that user's scores for all movies.

Comment: Yes you are right it should be -20. I was thinking about just updating by doing -= 20 instead. I am not sure if your output is correct or I am wrong but I believe I correctly calculated the Spider-Man film and got 128 as the final score while you got 88

Comment: 98 - 20 + 10 = 88. `popularityScore` is 98, the brand preferences dislike Marvel (-20), and the content type preferences like movies (+10). Let me know if I've misunderstood how the system is supposed to work.

Comment: Oh right, something else confused me. With the preferences, is it possible to make this program work where the preferences and content type remain in their original variables instead of being almost hardcoded into the preferences dict?

Comment: Yes, it's totally possible. I organized it in this way due to personal preference. You could change it so that, just like in your original solution, both the brand- and content type preferences are in separate variables, and the `get_movie_score` function in this case would have to be modified to accept three parameters instead of two. What I wouldn't change, however, is the conversion from JSON encoded string to dictionary: convert once at the start of the program, and then use the resulting dictionaries in the rest of the program.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: Unless of course, the preferences are meant to change over time, like with each movie for example, then my solution would have to be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the change! One more thing, sorry. Could I make the main function return a list instead of printing the values as it is right now? I have tired but I keep bumping into errors. Appreciate the help once again!

Comment: Since preferences can be modified or I might want to test this program for another user with different values I have made a variable called brand_preferences which holds the brand preferences and similarly for the content preferences and then I have just passed these in like: json.loads(brand_preferences)... I did not make any changes to the get_movie_score function and ran it and got the same, correct result. I was just now looking to get it to return a list

Comment: I've edited my answer. I wouldn't have the main function return the list, though. Right now the main function uses a list-comprehension to generate title-score strings. What do you intend on doing with that list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232985/discussion-between-ash-and-paul-m).